# Access element from its style object

Tags: javascript, html

Let, I created an object of style of an element.
`m = document.querySelector('.a').style;`
From this obj, how do I access the element itself? (if possible)

Temp. Note: There is no such question in StackOverflow yet.

Comment: Question is not clear, could you give us some more info on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't think you can. `CSSStyleDeclaration` objects don't contain a reference to the element they came from.